# Do we say "The police confiscated his car" in everyday conversation?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Do we say "**confiscate**" in everyday conversation?

For example,

A robber stole a car and "**The police confiscated his car**"

A student brought a knife to school and "**The security man confiscated his knife**"

Comment: Yes. Why would you think not?

Comment: @StephenS, "confiscate" sounds formal, do we have a more idiomatic term?

Comment: “took” or “took away”, maybe, but “confiscate” doesn’t sound excessively formal. As a teen, we would complain about teachers confiscating our phones during class.

Comment: *seize* is also used.

Answer (score 3):

Confiscate is quite formal, but the correct word for a formal situation in which the police are taking something.  That is a formal process and the specific word is better than the more general "take".

Confiscate is not very formal and it would be normal for a parent or teacher to confiscate a teenager's property as behaviour management.

> You're grounded for a month, and I'm confiscating your phone for 24 hours.
>
> Oh no, please don't take my phone!

Answer (score 1):

The verb **impound** is used when 'confiscating' a car. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/impound) has

> **impound**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> **1** Seize and take legal custody of (something, especially a vehicle, goods, or documents) because of an infringement of a law.
> *vehicles parked where they cause an obstruction will be impounded*

The word 'confiscate' would not apply to a stolen car, because it does not belong to the thief. The seized vehicle is usually taken to a [**pound³**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pound).

> **1.1** A place where illegally parked motor vehicles removed by the police are kept until their owners pay a fine in order to reclaim them.

---

The word **confiscate** would be appropriate for the knife example, and I don't think it is particularly formal. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/confiscate) has

> **confiscate**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> **1** Take or seize (someone's property) with authority.
> *the guards confiscated his camera*